# Guest Session does not load ssL certificates on firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, ssl, certificates

I started using edubuntu for a very old computer that originally ran on Windows XP.  It ran perfectly well until the latest update.  The issue is that it does not load the ssL certificates while logged into the guest account - it used to without a problem.  Now, before a guest tries to use the internet (using firefox) - I have to load all the ssL certificates required.  Since the guest account does not save information to disk - this needs to be done every time.  Now, If I switch to the primary account - there are no problems - the firefox runs without issue.

So my options are either:
1- giving admin access to a guest (who can then make changes to system) - or
2- opening a guest session, opening firefox, and loading all ssL certificates every single time.

Has anyone dealt with this issue in the past???  Does anyone know how to fix it???

Comment: can you explain the error when you don't load the certificates explicitely and how you load them and from where?

Comment: when browsing attempted, the browser says "connection is not secure" and won't allow me to move forward - I have to navigate to http://achieve.lausd.net/Page/11048 - here there are certificates for various O/S - I choose the win certs for Firefox (LAUSD-ROOT-CA2.CRT and LAUSD-SUB-CA2.CRT)  once done, the computer is able to navigate without issue - however, since all this needs to be done from the guest account, the certificates are not saved and therefore need to be downloaded every time the computer is used.  hope the answer provided the information you required - thanks for following up

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the guest session defaults to include the required certificates by following the instructions in this Help Wiki article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession